# How to read content of /proc/[pid]/ns/mnt?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I’m learning Linux (Centos 6) namespace. I think this file should contains `mount` information of the process.
Do you know how to read the content of this symbol-link using shell?

Comment: `cat /proc/[pid]/ns/mnt`?

Comment: @KamilCuk Invlid argument. That file is not cat-able.

Comment: It doesn't contain mount information of the process. It's not even a real file - it has no contents - the purpose is to use with the `setns` syscall to get into the same mount namespace as that process.

Comment: @user253751 you could post that as an answer.

Comment: @user253751 then, where does the mount info store?

Comment: @user1633272 i think /proc/pid/mounts?

Comment: @user253751 The mnt-namespace should be shared across processes with same mnt-namespace? But /proc/pid/mounts is per process.

Comment: @user1633272 indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readlink` will return you something, but it's not really useful.
E.g.:

```
# readlink /proc/141580/ns/mnt 
mnt:[4026533639]
```

`/proc/[pid]/mounts` will get you the mount points, and they will be the same for all the processes in that namespace.
Of course also the value of readlink .../ns/mnt will be the same.

You can easily test that with a docker run and a docker exec on that container (not sure if you have docker on centos 6, but you could experiment on other boxes).